# Test for number in range, except for certain values

Tags: ruby

I'd like to test if a number `n` falls within the range 1 to 26, except for values that have repeated digits (so 11, 22):

```
(n=24).between?(1, 26) # => true, ok
 (n=1).between?(1, 26) # => true, ok
(n=11).between?(1, 26) # => true (but I want this to return false)
```

Is there a better way to achieve this than doing:

```
[*1..10, *12..21, *23..26].include?(n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a better way to achieve this than doing:
>
> ```
> [*1..10, *12..21, *23..26].include?(n)
> ```

Yes, of course. Compose your complex check from simpler parts. First part checks the range, another rejects numbers with repeated digits

```
n.between?(1, 26) && !has_repeated_digits?(n)
```

Where check for repeated digits could be implemented like this:

```
def has_repeated_digits?(n)
  n.to_s.chars.uniq != n.to_s.chars

  # or, in newer rubies (2.4+)
  n.digits.uniq != n.digits
end
```

Or, you can trade some RAM to avoid computation and store all your "invalid" numbers in a `Set` or something. You can change this however you want and the original condition doesn't need to be touched. The beauty of abstraction.

Comment: Suggestion to break down the checks will definitely make it more readable, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

if the range is limited and precise as in your case, you are doing good. a little better way would be subtraction.

```
([*1..26] - [11, 22]).include?(n=11)
```

Other methods would definitely be better but does not do any good than more computation than required for your usecase.

As in the comments, array building is expensive too, if you have a concept of `constants` or `global variables` defined in your app, then you can define a constant during initialization like the following:

```
ARRAY_RANGE = [*1..26] - [11, 22]
```

and when you have to check, you just need to:

```
ARRAY_RANGE.include?(n=11)
```

Comment: Array lookup is O(N). And building the array isn't free either. But for teeny tiny arrays like this, it probably doesn't matter much.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev exactly! since the range is defined and so short, it's negligible.

Comment: Performance could be improved greatly by using `Set` instead of array. O(1) lookups FTW :)

Comment: I see, can you explain with an example? @SergioTulentsev

Answer (score 1):

```
24.between?(1, 26) && !(24%100%11).zero? # => true
1.between?(1, 26) && !(1%100%11).zero?   # => true
11.between?(1, 26) && !(11%100%11).zero? # => false
22.between?(1, 26) && !(22%100%11).zero? # => false
```

Comment: Also, in this example, 22 should not pass the check too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It doesn't. `22.between?(1, 26) && !(22%100%11).zero? #=> false`

Comment: I _think_ this is the fastest and most memory efficient of all solutions here. With a severe limitation, though :)

Comment: The question might have not been clear. I interpreted that the OP wants to exclude having a duplicated lowest two digits. If the OP simply meant duplicated consecutive digits in any position, then that is not what my answer is intended to do.

Comment: Might not even be consecutive. Like in 303, for example. Although yes, I have no idea about that problem's constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash. Fill the hash with numbers to skip. And check existance key:

```
a = [11, 22]
h = Hash[a.map {|x| [x, 1]}]
n=24

n.between?(1, 26) && !h.key?(n)
```

Comment: For such hashes, where you don't care about the value, only that the key exists, it is semantically better to use `Set`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Plot twist : Ruby's [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is just a Hash for which we don't care about the value. :) I do get your point though.

Comment: @EricDuminil: yeah, I know. I said "_semantically_ better" :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter:

```
a=(1..26).to_a - [11,22]
```

Then, use the `include?` methods.

(Note that it will remove all occurrences)